# Understanding nginx backup

Tags: nginx, node.js

Consider the following setup. Will each request check for availability of 1.2.3.4 or does nginx mark a server as failed and only attempts a retry every so often?

```
upstream backend {
    server 1.2.3.4:80;
    server 4.5.6.7:80 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will mark the server as failed after `max_fails` failed attempts (default 1) and for a duration of `fail_timeout` (default 10 seconds). If you set `max_fails` to a value larger then 1, the failed attempts also need to occur in a time window of length `fail_timeout`.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: Thank you for this information Sven! I've updated the question with more details as I'm still unable to resolve my problem with 502 errors.

Comment: @Anshul: Editing a question so drastically that it invalidates already given answers is considered very poor style. Please ask a new question and then roll back the edit to the original form.

Comment: Appreciate the input Sven. Doing this right now.